# Как в Linux подключить dll по пути (а не зарегистрированную в системе) из dotnet.core

Tags: .net-core, .net

Задача - воспользоваться dll (native-не управляемый код) которая лежит по известному пути из dotnet.core.

Использовать "Стандартный" прием:

```
[DllImport("libSystem.dylib")]
private static extern int getpid();
```

нельзя - на момент компиляции путь к библиотеке не известен.

В widows я выкручивался так:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
```

Функция "LoadLibrary" позволяла загрузить dll в домен и потом по ссылке через "GetProcAddress" получать имена процедур и вызывать их

Как подобное можно сделать в Linux?

Comment: Если это библиотека из состава .NET Core, то вы ее можете использовать без всяких ухищрений. Я не понимаю, что и зачем вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Если это какая-то сторонняя библиотека, то не проще ли будет таскать ее с собой? Положите в папку проекта и все.

Comment: Забыл указать - библиотека native-не управляемый код, и написана не мною.

Comment: @Alexanderp С собой не получится таскать - это библиотека сбербанка, обслуживающая эквайринг. Если ее запустить из другого места она не заработает - ей нужно куча всего из ее родного каталога установки дистрибутива сбербанка. Плюс ее версия должна соответствовать дистрибутиву сбербанка.

Comment: Понятно. Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49270527/5045688)